# Excel - select next item off list that is not already in array (no VBA)

Tags: excel, match, lookup, vlookup

I have a list of items, say 1 - 10 ordered smallest to biggest in cells c1-c10.  I currently have a formula in a2 which will lookup the value a1 on that list, and then return the next item.

So if a1=2, then my formula will return 3.  However, I would like it to also look at another list, and not answer if that number is already on that list.  Ie, if the second list contained 3,4,7, and a1=2, then my formula should return 5.

Both the first lookup list and the second list can be any length.  I can't use VBA.  I'm somewhat stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like homework.... not that you need it anyway, but why can't you use VBA?

Comment: I'm a bit old for homework! It's for a competition - using VBA is against the rules.  It's a small part of the larger problem.

Comment: Fair play - I see you have a solution now anyway. Good luck then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the second range is in `D2:D4` then try this "array formula"

`=SMALL(IF(C1:C10>A1,IF(COUNTIF(D2:D4,C1:C10)=0,C1:C10)),1)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That will return the smallest value in `C1:C10` which is bigger than `A1` but not in the `D2:D4` list ( `COUNTIF` does that second check)

If there is no value that qualifies you get `#NUM!` error